# An ideal $I$ of the ring $R$ is a semiprime ideal if and only if the quotient ring $R/I$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Proposition: An ideal $I$ of the ring $R$ is a semiprime ideal if and only if the quotient ring $R/I$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements.

Proof?: Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ s.t. $I=\sqrt{I}$; that is, $\forall r\in R$ such that $r^n \in I$, for some $n \in \Bbb{Z}^+$, r *must* be in $I$, as well. Thus, $\forall \pi \in R$ such that $\pi + I \neq I$, $\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}^+$, $(\pi + I)^k = \pi^k + I \neq I$, because $\pi^k$ cannot be in $I$. Conversely, if $R/I$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, then $\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}^+, \forall r \in R$, $(r+I)^k=r^k + I\neq I$. So $r^k \notin I$. Note that $r+I \neq I \Leftrightarrow r \notin I$. Thus, if $r \notin I$, then $r^k \notin I$, $\forall k \in \Bbb{Z}^+$. In other words, $\forall r \in R$, $r^k \in I \Leftrightarrow r \in I$. Hence, $I$ is a semiprime ideal of $R$.

Comment: Looks good. You should really try to see the statement "$r\in I$" as equivalent to "$r\equiv 0 \pmod{I}$". Thus the statement that $I$ is semiprime means "$r^k\equiv 0 \pmod{I}$ implies $r\equiv 0\pmod{I}$", which exactly means that $R/I$ has no nilpotents. It's not meant to be a complicated thing --- just a convenient rephrasing. In ring theory it is common to say "$I$ is a *blah* ideal if and only if $R/I$ is a *blah* ring".

Comment: I might be mistaken, but the forward direction of your proof looks like you are taking your hypothesis to be that $I$ is radical. Is this intended? What is your definition of semiprime? I think you actually want the proposition to be for $I$ a radical ideal, right?

Comment: @PrinceM: The definition I'm using is $I$ is semiprime iff $I=\sqrt{I}$.